# How to assign drupal webform to drupal node/block?

Tags: 6

i am using drupal 6.0 and webform modules to create webforms but i have no idea about asigning webforms to drupal node/block. so please help me and give some ideas and suggestion about this.

Comment: This could be answered by reading the top Google hit for "Drupal webform block".

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the [Webform Block](http://drupal.org/project/webformblock) module. It is stable and compatible with Drupal 6.

> Allows embedding a webform node into a block which can be positioned in any block region (theme space permitting).
>
> Handles redirecting back to the current page on validation errors.
>
> A good use for this is to add a site wide contact form inline on your pages, such as in the footer or sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

You *should not* use Webform Block if you are using a recent version of Webform: "The functionality of this module is now included in Webform 3.3. Do not install this module at the same time as Webform 3.x." (see http://drupal.org/project/webformblock)

Just use Webform module.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in node or block

```
$submission = array();
  $enabled = TRUE;
  $preview = FALSE;
  print drupal_get_form('webform_client_form_XXX', $node, $submission, $enabled, $preview);
```